# Create symlink to the final target of another symlink

Tags: linux, bash, symbolic-link, ln

Suppose a have a **symlink** named `A`

If I execute this:

```
ln A B -s
```

then B points to A, having created a chain of symlinks: `B->A->some`

Is there any option for `ln` to link directly to the **final target**, without writing it explicitly? to get `B->some`?

I would do that with readlink like this:

```
ln "$(readlink A -f)" B -s
```

But I think it should exist some option do it just with `ln`.

Comment: sorry my bad. I corrected it already

Comment: I corrected that one too already. I like to put flags at the end. I think it's more readable. It works in almost all cli tools.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That option doesn't exist in "standard" `ln`; the target path is always taken as a literal string with no other processing.

However, if the symlink points to an absolute path (i.e. `readlink A` == `readlink -f A`), you can *copy* the symlink instead:

```
cp -a A B
```

(This will also happen to work with relative symlinks *if* both symlinks are in the same directory, and in some other limited situations.)

Additionally, in GNU Coreutils' `ln`, you can use the `-r`/`--relative` option to achieve this:

```
ln -s -r A B
```

(As the name implies, this will always result in a *relative* symlink being made – even if the original was pointing to an absolute path. It would be nice if there was also an opposite option for converting relative inputs into absolute targets, but currently there isn't one.)